# How can we override a class in prestashop without placing it in the override folder?

Tags: prestashop

i would like to override the HTMLTemplate class but my customer customizes prestashop core elements directly (which is a bad practiceà and his disabled overrides from BO so that any developed modules cannot override any prestashop class or template. my question is can we override a class in prestashop without insert it into override folder in our module? and if yes how can we do it?

Comment: I don't see the point? just turn on the override option, remove the overrides from modules which you don't like and add your own override. Why try to bypass the system? Just remove what you don't need and use the system like it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify load method in PrestaShopAutoload class, ignore default behavior and require your override class from your path if $className parameter == HTMLTemplate

It is bad practice too, but if you need to override more classes you only touch one core file, not several.

If overrides have been disabled you must use workarounds.